# Wicket with Spring declarative transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, wicket, aspectj

It is  possible to use the Spring Framework's @Transactional support outside of a Spring container. In reference documentation is chapter about AspectJ aspect. I'm trying to use it in my wicket application, but with no positive result.

application-context.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wicket.app"/>
<context:spring-configured />

<bean id="annotationTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
</bean>
```

In my form class annotated by @Configurable, I have:

```
@Transactional
public void process(IFormSubmittingComponent submittingComponent) {
    super.process(submittingComponent);
    getDao().getEntityManager().flush();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Can only perform operation while a transaction is active.
```

Answer (score 4):

You *might* be able to get this working using AspectJ [load-time-weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw), but that's a very complex solution for a simple problem.

If you need declarative transactions, then I suggest you move the transactional logic from the wicket component down into a Spring bean, and invoke the Spring bean from the wicket object. The Spring bean would have the transactional annotations, and would be proxied correctly by the Spring container.

Comment: Yeah, my fault. This simple solution is better. There is no need to exaggerate.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Wicket. But is your 'form class' (the one that contains method annotated with `@Transactional`) Spring managed code? i.e. Who creates the instances of the class?

If it's not, that Spring will not provide `@Transactional` support (neither will `@Autowired` work, etc).

Comment: @Transactional may be used outside Spring container, for example on entity class <a href=http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj>documentation</a>. But I did something wrong, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you refering to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj. Then yes - you are right, it would add `@Transactional` support for non-Spring managed code, but all of these classes still have to undergo some kind of processing by Spring (what they call `spring-aspects.jar`).

Comment: I'm trying to add aspectj processing, but it doesn't work. Any sugestions why?